# Repeated use of fixtures in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am learning pytest, particularly its fixtures which are different from the xUnit setUp() and tearDown() paradigm. Say I have the following test:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def foo():
    return 'foo'


@pytest.fixture()
def bar():
    return 'bar'


@pytest.fixture()
def baz():
    return 'baz'


@pytest.fixture()
def foobar(foo, bar):
    return foo + bar


@pytest.fixture()
def foobaz(foo, baz):
    return foo + baz


def test(foobar, foobaz):
    print('test')
    print(foobar)
    print(foobaz)
```

In this example, the `foo()` fixture is used twice, once by `foobar()` and again by `foobaz()`. If I reuse the same fixture multiple times for a single test, is the fixture function called once and its result cached? Or is it called each time that it is used? In my contrived example, the returned value is static, so there is no problems. I can imagine many situations where the returned value is more dynamic and I need to guarantee that I have the exact same instance everywhere it is used.

Answer (score 5):

pytest fixture's life could be controlled with `scope` argument. There are basically four scopes `function, class, module, session`. The default scope is `function` which is the one your fixtures are using.

In the case of `function` scope, the fixture would be called for each test function on which the fixture is used.

A `class` scoped fixture is called once per test class through out the test cycle and so is `module` scoped fixture (once per test module).

A `session` scoped fixture is called once per test session.

More reading and examples for different scopes is available [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) and [fixture function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.fixtures.fixture)

Comment: So for `test()` in my example, will `foo()` only be called once even though it is used by both `foobar()` and `foobaz()`?

Comment: that is correct, they are called once per function irrespective of them being reused in other fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

A fixture is only called when it is used and it will be only called once based on the scope.

If the scope is `session` then it will only be called one for the whole execution. In your case since you have not specified the scope, it assumed `function`.

So below would be the execution order

```
foo
bar
foo + bar
baz
foo + baz
```

As you can see `baz` only called when `foo + baz` method was requested.

- If you remove both the parameters from your test function. Nothing will be called even once.
- If you remove `foobaz` then `baz` and `foobaz` will never be called
- If you insert another function `test2(foobar, foobaz)`, then whole cycle will be repeated as the scope of fixture is per/function

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `foo()` will be called only once and the result will be passed to both `foobar()` and `foobaz()`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes and that is just for your function `test` , if you have another test function then it will be called again for that test

Comment: Yes, I understand that fixtures are called for each test. My question is regarding what happens during a single test. Thank you for your clarification.